# Going deep... or a museaum piece?

Tags: riddle, word

> 1. #### Start with a four-letter edible ectothermic animal.
> 2. #### Remove three letters.
> 3. #### Add a small insect and you have a 1994 Indian action film*.
> 4. #### Take something you have when you don’t have something else, remove its last letter and add it.
> 5. #### Rearrange a CEO and stick him on.
>
>    #### Apparently they thought I was... what did the geriatric egg do? The egg _______. Oh, wait that was incorrect English.

## What am I?

<sub>*I personally don't know anything about it</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with a four-letter edible ectothermic animal. Remove three letters.

Add a small insect and you have a 1994 Indian action film*

*@aguy found these two parts*,

> fish -> h -> anth

Take something you have when you don’t have something else, remove its last letter and add it.

> lack -> lacanth

Rearrange a CEO and stick him on.

> ceo -> coe -> coelacanth

Apparently they thought I was... what did the geriatric egg do?

> THE EGG STINKED / EXTINCT. [Coelacanths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coelacanth) were thought have gone extinct with the dinosaurs, but then rediscovered alive.

Comment: Well done! This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Partial:

Start with a four-letter edible ectothermic animal.

> Probably **fish**. The fish is ectothermic and edible.

Remove three letters.

> Removing the first 3 letters gives us **h**

Add a small insect.

> Ant. And we get **Anth**  which is the name of [an Indian movie from 1994](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anth)

Take something you have when you don’t have something else, remove its last letter and add it.

> What you have when don't have something else is you **miss** something. Apparently this is incorrect (due to the comment by the author).

Rearrange a CEO and stick him on.

> So, from CEO we can get coe, oec, oce, eco, eoc.

Comment: I'll leave you to work it further. We'll see if you are on the right track or not. Maybe I'll add hints later if it becomes necessary.

Comment: See edit.......

Comment: rot13: Abgr gung lbh pna'g _unir_ n zvff va gung frafr.

Answer (score 0):

Not done yet...

Start with a four-letter edible, ectothermic animal.

> **FISH** is both ectothermic and edible.

Remove three letters.

> **H**

Add a small insect and you have a 1994 Indian action movie

> **ANT** $+$ **H** $=$ **ANTH**

I didn't get any further than this...